Microsoft sign-in page infinite loop on my ASP.NET Web Forms Application
I implemented Microsoft authentication using Microsoft Entra ID and Owin in my ASP.NET Web Forms Application. The redirect URI i am using in my web.config are correct and same in Azure app registration, however for a certain redirect URI i keep on getting the Microsoft sign-in page over and over again, it never enters into my application.
The redirect URIs i have tried:

https://localhost/MyApp/Default.aspx --> Works
http://localhost/MyApp/Default.aspx --> Does not work
https://localhost/MyApp --> Does not work
http://localhost/MyApp --> Does not work

Also as far as i know http should work on localhost but in my case its giving infinite sign-in page
